# My JavaScript code has an error

Tags: javascript

This is my first my hands-on with Java script. I tried my best and got stuck here:

This is my output. I don't understand why I'm getting the undefined values in the last. Also because of this, final results are not coming properly:

```
COURSE GRADE CREDIT-HOURS
Math          A          4
Scie          A          3
          undefined          undefined
Total Grade points = NaN
Number of hours = undefined43
GPA = NaN
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var ch, gp, gpa;
  var grade;
  document.write("COURSE   GRADE   CREDIT-HOURS ");
  document.write("<hr>");
  document.write("<hr>");
  do {
    grade = prompt("Enter the score in this format : <subject name><space><Grade><space><credit>");
    var pro = grade.split(" ")[0];
    var mid = grade.split(" ")[1];
    var pre = grade.split(" ")[2];
    document.write(pro);
    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
    document.write(mid);
    document.write("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
    document.write(pre);
    document.write("<br>");

    switch (mid) {
      case "A":
        gp = gp + (pre * 4)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "B+":
        gp = gp + (pre * 3.5)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "B":
        gp = gp + (pre * 3)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "C+":
        gp = gp + (pre * 2.5)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "C":
        gp = gp + (pre * 2)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "D":
        gp = gp + (pre * 1)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;

      case "F":
        gp = gp + (pre * 0)
        ch = ch + pre;
        break;
    }

  } while (grade != "");
  document.write("Total Grade points = " + gp);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Number of hours = " + ch);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("GPA = " + (gp / ch));
  document.write("<br>");
</script>
```

Comment: Provide a working plunkr or JSfiddle for this. It will be hard to understand just by looking at this dead code.

Comment: Maybe you should initialize ch with 0.  `var ch = 0;`

Comment: Maybe add an alert (for debug) so you can assess as it goes along.

Comment: @AKA — Stackoverflow has [supported inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for **years**, there's no need to direct people to third party hosting .

Comment: It is correct that ch is undefined. You declared it, but not defined.

Comment: Also &nbsp; is ignored by HTML

Comment: I defined ch, it is not working still.. I'm getting that undefined values

Answer (score 0):

Initialize variables.

```
var gp = 0;
var ch = 0;
```

The code is getting executed once after the null input.
Add a break statement

```
if (grade == "") {break;}
```

after

```
grade = prompt("Enter the...");
```

**Edit:**
Also surround `document.write("GPA = " + (gp / ch));` to handle case when `ch = 0`.
For ex-

```
if(ch != 0) {
    document.write("GPA = " + (gp / ch));
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: That is not enough. Then all calculations at end will be NaN

Comment: Yes I have. Have you?

Comment: Create a [mcve] and then hit enter immediately and your code will show NaN in the calculations

Comment: Why would you show a NaN to an end user - how would they know what that meant? It should be 0 or not shown

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't shown `NaN` to end user. However, OP is using this as learning example. I thought it's okay to get `NaN` while learning. Anyway, the problem was getting out of the loop correctly, which I think I have solved.

Comment: _I don't understand why I'm getting the undefined values in the last_ - I disagree - language dependent errors and internal error messages needs to be caught and handled or prevented as I do in my version

Comment: Did you see my answer? At the end? And sorry, I read "Yes, I WOULD shown NaN to end user"

Comment: Yes. It shows many pitfalls one may encounter in such example. I don't know whether you should tell this to learner in one go!

Comment: Well, my example is still structured exactly like his - I only answered to give him better solutions to standard issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please study this example.

Note the parseInt and test that the divisor is > 0

Also note I replaced the document.write with an innerHTML of demo as I suspect you want - if you use document.write, you cannot run the code in a function after the page has loaded

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var ch=0, gp=0, gpa=0, grade,
  html = "COURSE   GRADE   CREDIT-HOURS <hr><hr>";
  do {
    grade = prompt("Enter the score in this format : <subject name><space><Grade><space><credit>");
    var pro = grade.split(" ")[0];
    var mid = grade.split(" ")[1];
    var pre = grade.split(" ")[2];
    if (
      isNaN(pre) || pre.trim() ==""
    ) {
      break; // stop
    }
    pre = parseInt(pre,10); // make it a number
    mid = mid=="" ? "":mid.toUpperCase(); // your switch is case sensitive
    html += pro;
    html += "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    html += mid;
    html += "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    html += pre;
    html += "<br>";

    ch += pre; // always

    switch (mid) {
      case "A":
        gp += (pre * 4  ); break;
      case "B+":
        gp += (pre * 3.5); break;
      case "B":
        gp += (pre * 3  ); break;
      case "C+":
        gp += (pre * 2.5); break;
      case "C":
        gp += (pre * 2  ); break;
      case "D":
        gp += (pre * 1  ); break;
      case "F":
        gp += (pre * 0  ); break;
    }

  } while (grade != "");
html += "Total Grade points = " + gp;
html += "<br>";
html += "Number of hours = " + ch;
html += "<br>";
if (gp > 0 && ch > 0) html += "GPA = " + (gp / ch).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=html; // now it can be in a function too
</script>
```